# Define a new math-delimiter in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to define a new math-delimiter for texstudio syntax highlighting ?

For example, I would like to indicate that the `\begin{mblock}...\end{mblock}` environment is a math-delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `user.cwl` file with the next contents:

```
\begin{mblock}#\math
\end{mblock}#\math
```

Move this file into the `%appdata%\texstudio\completion\user` or `.config/texstudio/completion/user` directory.

In the TeXstudio:

Options / Configure TeXstudio / Completion

Click on the checkbox of `user.cwl` / OK

That's all!